# How do I filter a list of vectors in Clojure?

Tags: list, vector, filter, clojure

I am new to Clojure and learning the properties of various data structures in Clojure. Here, I have a list of vectors as follows:

```
(["1" "Christiano Ronaldo" "Portugal" "35"] 
 ["2" "Lionel Messi" "Argentina" "32"] 
 ["3" "Zinedine Zidane" "France" "47"])
```

where the first element of each vector is the id. How do I filter out single vectors from the list based on the id? For eg., `id = 1` should return

```
["1" "Christiano Ronaldo" "Portugal" "35"]
```

I tried doing the same on a nested-map:

```
(def footballers 
    [
        {:id 1 :name "Christiano Ronaldo" :country "Portugal" :age 35}
        {:id 2 :name "Lionel Messi" :country "Argentina" :age 32}
        {:id 3 :name "Zinedine Zidane" :country "France" :age 47}
    ]
)
```

and was successful using the `filter` function

```
(filter #(= (:id %) 1) footballers)
```

Result:

```
({:id 1, :name "Christiano Ronaldo", :country "Portugal", :age 35})
```

How do I do the same in a list of vectors using `filter` function?

Comment: Turning your tuples into a map i'd consider a good idea - giving things names is very powerful and you even had an answer for your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(filterv #(= "1" (first %)) footballers)  ; or `filter`

   ;=> [["1" "Christiano Ronaldo" "Portugal" "35"]]  ; vector containing 1 vector
```

Please see [this list of documentation](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation).

Comment: That was quick. I was struggling with the pred part of that filter function. Thank you.